# After systemctl suspend Ubuntu 20.04 goes to sleep, then wakes up by itself after several seconds

Tags: suspend, systemd

I was fixing a boot issue on my computer (I do not know if it is related). After that `systemctl suspend` was working just fine.
Then I added a unit for systemctl and ran:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

After that `systemctl suspend` stopped working again. My theory is that one of systemd units is responsible for that. Is it possible to verify it?

I entered suspend on exactly 18:07:00 and the computer woke up on 18:07:08. Here is [journalctl snapshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11CKFgs7B_kkVds3ygdaB8DqtxgXSOsUX/view?usp=sharing) .

```
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 polkitd(authority=local)[796]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10152:752858 (s>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 ModemManager[870]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5135] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  e>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5136] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5139] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deac>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 polkitd(authority=local)[796]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10152:752858 >
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 whoopsie[1510]: [18:07:00] offline
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 dbus-daemon[774]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 dbus-daemon[774]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:d7:aa:f6:ed:a6 reason=3 locally_g>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <warn>  [1691975220.5307] sup-iface[0x5590422a93f0,wlp2s0]: connection dis>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event f>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5311] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> d>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Withdrawing address record for 2607:fb90:9f0c:c1e6:dfa3:8a90:c231:9f0e on wl>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Withdrawing address record for 2607:fb90:9f0c:c1e6:3e15:c2ff:fee6:104e on wl>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address 2607:fb90>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3e1>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Registering new address record for fe80::3e15:c2ff:fee6:104e on wlp2s0.*.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3e15:c2ff:fee6:104e on wlp2s0.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3e1>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 whoopsie[1510]: [18:07:00] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5501] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5502] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.12.181 on wlp2s0.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 avahi-daemon[763]: Interface wlp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 whoopsie[1510]: [18:07:00] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 gnome-shell[1921]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access po>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5542] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: com>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975220.5547] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> u>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-100
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 nm-dispatcher[10169]: run-parts: failed to stat component /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-dae>
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd-sleep[10175]: Suspending system...
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.024 seconds
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 18:07:00 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.093 seconds) done.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: EC: event blocked
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: EC: EC started
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: CPU1 is up
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: CPU2 is up
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: CPU3 is up
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: CPU4 is up
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0x3
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: CPU5 is up
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x5
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: CPU6 is up
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x7
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: CPU7 is up
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Slot(0): Card present
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 rtkit-daemon[1004]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 rtkit-daemon[1004]: Demoting known real-time threads.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 rtkit-daemon[1004]: Demoted 0 threads.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: video LNXVIDEO:00: Restoring backlight state
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: PM: suspend exit
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 systemd-sleep[10175]: System resumed.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 systemd-logind[820]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975228.4251] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  e>
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975228.4251] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unav>
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 ModemManager[870]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975228.4272] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_L>
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (8)
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Inter>
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975228.5021] sup-iface[0x5590422a9300,wlp2s0]: supports 1 sca>
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975228.5028] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: sta>
Aug 13 18:07:08 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975228.5028] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> di>
Aug 13 18:07:10 alex-Mac512 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Slot(0): No link
Aug 13 18:07:10 alex-Mac512 ModemManager[870]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci00>
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 wpa_supplicant[826]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3418] policy: auto-activating connection 'ab-home-tm' >
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3423] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection>
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3424] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> p>
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3428] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3432] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config>
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3435] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point>
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3435] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-au>
Aug 13 18:07:12 alex-Mac512 NetworkManager[775]: <info>  [1691975232.3438] sup-iface[0x5590422a9300,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc >
```

Comment: Found the fix that is almost 4 years old! https://superuser.com/questions/1495343/ubuntu-on-macbook-pro-doesnt-suspend-properly